# Find Maven repository where a dependency is stored

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository, find

I'm working on a project with several corporate remote Maven repositories, each hosting many dozens of dependencies.  The entire project uses hundreds of dependencies and I need a way to **quickly determine which remote repository a dependency is stored on**.

Does Maven provide an easy way to do this or do I need to search through each repository's dependency listing myself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [project dependencies report](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html) has the information you want.  You can quickly generate just this report using

```
mvn project-info-reports:dependencies
```

and open the target/site/dependencies.html file.  Look at the last section in this report (dependency repository locations) for the info you want.

A sample of this report is [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/dependencies.html).

Comment: This doesn't work when a maven dependency can't be resolved