# How to find source package manager in android

Tags: android, maven, center

I want to see available versions of 3rd party libraries that I use in my android project. I looked at maven central and jcenter but I couldn't find. I have 2 question:

1. How can I look versions of packages I use
2. Is there a way to figure out which package manager is used to load a specific library.

By the way the library I mentioned is com.theartofdev.evmodo:android-image-cropper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` to see latest versions of your dependencies.

android-image-cropper releases available at https://bintray.com/arthurhub/maven/Android-Image-Cropper . (Click Set Me Up button to see repository configuration required for using this repo)

To see which jars are download from which repositories check this [Find Maven repository where a dependency is stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334004/find-maven-repository-where-a-dependency-is-stored)